# Calculating price of a Product after Comission without loss in original price

Tags: percentages

Say a product value is 100 and I need to pay comission of 27% for every sale. Which means 27 so i get 73 in hand. Now in case if i don't want to loose margin and want full 100 in hand then what will be the formula to calculate the price for which calculating the 27% will give me 100 in hand . I'm not sure whether i made my quey clearly understandable. Hope you got my query...Help me out pls.

To be more clear : Say , 100 is X and we have percentage as 27. Now i need a formula which will give the result Z . Calculating 27% of Z should give me 100 (X) in hand after Comission deduction. So that I have no loss .

Comment: What does 'for which calculating the 27% will give me 100' mean?

Comment: You want to solve $.73x=1$?

Comment: @Mastermind817 Say , 100 is X and we have percentage as 27. Now need a formula which will give the result Z . Calculating 27% of Z should give me 100 (X) in hand after Comission deduction. So that I have no loss . Whether this is clear ??

Comment: @saulspatz  Have tried be more clear in my previous reply . Whether that is clear for you ?

Comment: What is unclear about what I said?

Comment: @saulspatz sorry I not meant that . I thought I was unclear in forming question . So tried to be more clear .

Comment: @saulspatz u mean I need to replace x with the value in 73x=1 ??

Comment: $x=1/.73=1.33698...$ so increase the price by $33.7\%$

Comment: @saulspatz first of all sorry for being soo basic in asking doubts.. till 1.33698 I'm clear . After that  how it became 33.7% from there . Also 100+33.7% = 133.7 now deducting 27% in 133.7 gives 97.601 not 100 ???

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.  I has an extra $3$.  $1/.73=1.3698$ so the price should be increased by $37\%$

Comment: @saulspatz . Great 37% gives answer. Just one more clarity needed for me . Sorry I am may look ver noob. How 1.3697 became 37% ?

Comment: I just rounded it off.  Use as many decimal places as you like.

Comment: @saulspatz so which means in 1.3698 I should ignore the value before decimal that is 1 and take the value after decimal which is 3698 and round it off that is 37.. am i wright ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathrm{margin}=1-\frac{1}{1 +\mathrm{markup}}$$

Or
$$1-\mathrm{margin}=\frac{1}{1+\mathrm{markup}}$$

Which is :$$\frac{1}{1-\mathrm{margin}}-1=\mathrm{markup}$$

Plugging in $\mathrm{margin}=0.27$ we get: $$\frac{1}{0.73}-1=\frac{27}{73}$$